# Do we need different application forms for each applicant for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk

Do we have to fill out a different visa form for each applicant for a UK visa? Can it be filled in with the same id or does every form need a different id? Actually, I am applying for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

From the same id you can fill different applications (e.g. for your family) from the section "Apply for someone else".